# JTable setCellRenderer to format a text field to date?

Tags: swing, date, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I have a SQLite database with a date stored as `VARCHAR` (yyyy-mm-dd), for example `'2013-01-25'`.
My query retrieves the records from the table and displays it as stored.  I need to display the `VARCHAR` data in my `JTable` as 'Friday January 25, 2013'.  I suspect using **setCellRenderer** for the column containing the VARCHAR is the way to go.  Further, I think it will be a two step process: first, converting the VARCHAR to a date value then formatting the date as desired.  I can do so as follows if I grab the VARCHAR value from the `JTable` and display it in a `JTextField`:

```
MyDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(rs.getString("My_Date"));
```

and then formatting it as desired

```
MyDateStr = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE MMMM d, yyyy").format(MyDate);
```

That's all well and good; however, I need the formatted display in the `JTable` column.  I've never used `setCellRenderer`, so I could use some help getting started.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Post by `Rob Camick` about [Table Format Renderers](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/11/table-format-renderers/) may solve your problem.

**UPDATE:**

I tried an example (as I am also curious to look `DateFormat` in JTable which I have not done so far) using [mKorbel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6517504/967638) code. The format which I have given as `input` is `"2013-01-25"`.

[image: Date Format Example]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;

public class JTableDateFormat {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object[][] data = {
                       {"Amar", "2013-01-25"},
                       {"Sammy", "2013-01-25"} 
                      };
    Object[] columnNames = {"Name", "Date"};
    JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellRenderer(new DateRenderer());
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(400, 100));
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}


class DateRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Date dateValue;
private SimpleDateFormat sdfNewValue = new SimpleDateFormat("EE MMM dd hh:mm:ss z yyyy");
private String valueToString = "";

@Override
public void setValue(Object value) {
    if ((value != null)) {
        String stringFormat = value.toString();
        try {
            dateValue = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(stringFormat);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        valueToString = sdfNewValue.format(dateValue);
        value = valueToString;
    }
    super.setValue(value);
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!!  That's exactly what I needed to get over the hump.

Answer (score 0):

Make a class like this...

```
  public class DateRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    public DateRenderer() { // This is a contructor
        DateFormatter formatter = new DateFormatter("yyyy-MM-dd");
    }

    public class DateFormatter extends SimpleDateFormat { //This another class within a class

        public DateFormatter(String pattern) {
            super(pattern);
        }
    }
}
```

> And add this to your panel >> jTable.setDefaultRenderer(Date.class, new DateRenderer());

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please explain a little more, on how this answer improves the already existing one and how it solves the problem