# JTable Date Column cannot be edited

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable, abstracttablemodel

I am developing a desktop application in java with NetBeans 8.0
 there is a JTable with a custom made table model. However I am able to 
edit a column with the Date data type.

Below are the code snippets.

```
   public class DuesTableModel extends AbstractTableModel implements TableModelListener {

 private List<List<Object>> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
 private String[] header = { "ID"," PAYMENT YEAR" , "AMOUNT"};  // Payment year is a date
  datatype

 private int minRowCount = 5;    

  public DuesTableModel()
 { super(); }

 public List<List<Object>> getDataList() { 
    return dataList;
 }

 public void setDataList(List<List<Object>> dataList) {  
    this.dataList = dataList;
    fireTableDataChanged();       
    fireTableStructureChanged();        
 }


 @Override
 public int getRowCount() {
    return Math.max(minRowCount, dataList.size());
  }

  @Override
  public int getColumnCount() {
    return header.length;
  }

  public void setHeader(String[] header) {
    this.header = header;
  }

   public String[] getHeader() {
    return header;
   }

   @Override
  public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col)
 {       
  int x = 0;
   for(List<Object> l : dataList)
  {
    if(x == row)
    {  l.set(col, value);}
      x++;        
   }
  fireTableCellUpdated(row,col);    
  }


   @Override
   public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {

     Object value = null;
    if(rowIndex < dataList.size())      
    {value = dataList.get(rowIndex).get(columnIndex);}
    return value;
    }

   @Override
   public String getColumnName(int col) {
   return header[col];
   }


   @Override
   public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < getRowCount(); row++)
        {   
            Object o = getValueAt(row, column);

            if (o != null)
            {
                return o.getClass();
            }              
        }
        return Object.class;
       }

      @Override
      public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {          
      return true; //col
      }


      @Override
      public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); 
      }

      }
```

After setting the isCellEditable method to true , cells in the other columns are now edititable except the Payment Year column which is a date datatype.

Any suggestion is welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use `DefaultTableModel` instead of `AbstractTableModel` and use `TableCellRenderer` to format the date column as `yyyy` to display only year.

sample code:

```
final String[] header = { "ID", " PAYMENT YEAR", "AMOUNT" };
final Object[][] data = { { "1", new Date(), 500 }, { "2", new Date(), 200 },};
final DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, header);

final JTable table = new JTable(model) {
    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
        switch (column) {
            case 1:
                return Integer.class;
            case 2:
                return Date.class;
            default:
                return String.class;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
        return true;
    }
};

TableCellRenderer tableCellRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {

    SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");

    public java.awt.Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
            Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
            int row, int column) {
        if( value instanceof Date) {
            value = f.format(value);
        }
        return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected,
                hasFocus, row, column);
    }
};

table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellRenderer(tableCellRenderer);
```

Read more...

- [JTable setCellRenderer to format a text field to date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14529789/jtable-setcellrenderer-to-format-a-text-field-to-date)
- [Swing Tutorial - How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)